# How do I convert SQL query to sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have this block of sql - I'm using postgres DB.
How do I convert this query into sequelize ORM format? Thank you

```
select 
    to_char (created_at,'Mon') as month,
    extract (year from created_at) as year,
    id_product as product ,
    sum (sales) as sales
from 
    toiletries
group by 
    1, 2, 3
```

Comment: I suppose you can't do this using sequelize models. Only by a raw SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can attain this by using sequelize.literals()

```js
const Toiletries = sequelize.define('toiletries', {
    id_product: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    productName: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    }
    sales: {
     type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'toiletries'
});
Toiletries.findAll({
  group: ['id_product', 'createdAt'],
  attributes: [
    ['id_product', 'product'],
    [sequelize.literal('extract(YEAR FROM "createdAt")'), 'year'],
    [sequelize.literal('sum (sales)'), 'sum']
  ]
}).then((inn) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(inn))
});
```

You need to do some digging for the 'to_char' column. If you provide me the table structure we can also extract it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'll try to implement the query you post and let you know the outcomes